# Logon / Logoff Scripts with xcopy not Working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, xcopy, group-policy

I'm setting up a pair of logon and logoff scripts that will download and upload the users Outlook signatures automatically to and from their home directory (Z:\ drive).I'm using the scripts below, which work fine when run manually, but do not seem to be running at all (or at least not working) when set up as logon and logoff scripts with group policy. I have verified with gpresult that the scripts are indeed applied.

Logon Script (to download signatures):

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=Z:\batch.log
call :LOG >> %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
if exist "Z:\Signatures\" (
    xcopy /e /Y /D Z:\Signatures %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures
    )
```

Logoff Script (to upload signatures):

```
@echo off
set LOGFILE=Z:\batch.log
call :LOG >> %LOGFILE%
exit /B

:LOG
if not exist "Z:\Signatures\" (
    mkdir Z:\Signatures
    attrib +h Z:\Signatures /s /d
    )

xcopy /e /Y /D %appdata%\Microsoft\Signatures Z:\Signatures
```

Does anyone have an idea why this wouldn't be working?

Comment: Are you sure you even get into the `xcopy` part? Can you put a log entry before it and one behind, in order to be sure what happens? What's the ERRORLEVEL? Can you add `/F` to the `xcopy` command and redirect the output to the logfile in order to see what happens?

Comment: are you sure, `z:` is connected? It might be not, depending on how exactly you start the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by using `%homeshare%` instead of the mapped Z:\ drive